# Cannot create table in QuestDB with error that no space left on the device

Tags: questdb

When I try to crate table with index

```
CREATE TABLE NEW AS( SELECT DISTINCT * FROM OLD), 
index(RIC capacity 1000000) 
PARTITION BY MONTH
```

I get back error

```
io.questdb.cairo.CairoException: [2] No space left on device [need=99472113664]
```

I have 800+Gb free on the filesystem and able `OLD` is not particularly big, few Gb on disk. Any idea why I have the error?

Answer (score 0):

Index capacity is how many rows you expect per each symbol value on average. If you specify capacity of 1 million QuestDB will allocate 7Mb of data per each symbol value. If you try to insert 150k of distinct symbol values table will try allocate 1TB of space.

If you have few distinct symbol values and many rows per each of them then you increase **index** capacity. If you have many distinct symbols then you increase **symbol** capacity.